# Unexpected logs json appears in java file

Tags: java, android

i'm getting some json array response after deleting .impl file from root directory of my project. this file shows some line number and directory files in string as bunch of string json

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yo need to do some step:

1. Close your android studio properly.
2. Now go in this path **C:\Users\pc_name\ .** in this path you get one `.gradle` folder. Delete this folder.
3. Now open an android studio and wait for while complete process.

If this work then enjoy coding and in case this steps not working then Uninstall your android studio properly and install again.